# Play Framework: value withPrefix is not a member of api.ApiRouter

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I try to create sird Router in Play Framework (from official tutorial https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSirdRouter#Binding-sird-Router). 
I created the same structure and files but I get error after compile "Compilation error value withPrefix is not a member of api.ApiRouter".

ApiRouter (from official tutorial):

```
package api

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._


class ApiRouter @Inject()(controller: controllers.ApiController) extends SimpleRouter {
  override def routes: Routes = {
    case POST(p"/") => controller.message("test")
  }
}
```

ApiController works, routes file has error "cannot resolve api.ApiRouter" in

```
->      /api                        api.ApiRouter
```

I tried to change path and namespace in ApiRoter file (file put in app/controllers, namespace change to "controllers" and change to "controllers.ApiController" in routes line) but the same error.
Where did I mistake?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your mistake was, it's working for me. Maybe you should prepare a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and share it on github so we can have a look?!

Comment: Not sure but there is an alternative way of writing the method in routes file directly. For  example: POST             /api                       api.ApiRouter.methodName()